# Thread-safe Settings

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, atomic

Im writing some settings classes that can be accessed from everywhere in my multithreaded application. I will read these settings very often (so read access should be fast), but they are not written very often.

For primitive datatypes it looks like `boost::atomic` offers what I need, so I came up with something like this:

```
class UInt16Setting
{
    private:
        boost::atomic<uint16_t> _Value;
    public:
        uint16_t getValue() const { return _Value.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed); }
        void setValue(uint16_t value) { _Value.store(value, boost::memory_order_relaxed); }
};
```

**Question 1:** Im not sure about the memory ordering. I think in my application I don't really care about memory ordering (do I?). I just want to make sure that `getValue()` always returns a non-corrupted value (either the old or the new one). So are my memory ordering settings correct?

**Question 2:** Is this approach using `boost::atomic` recommended for this kind of synchronization? Or are there other constructs that offer better read performance?

I will also need some more complex setting types in my application, like `std::string` or for example a list of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint`s. I consider all these setting values as immutable. So once I set the value using `setValue()`, the value itself (the `std::string` or the list of endpoints itself) does not change anymore. So again I just want to make sure that I get either the old value or the new value, but not some corrupted state.

**Question 3:** Does this approach work with `boost::atomic<std::string>`? If not, what are alternatives?

**Question 4:** How about more complex setting types like the list of endpoints?  Would you recommend something like `boost::atomic<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint>>>`? If not, what would be better?

Comment: Re-examine the requirement of allowing multiple threads to read and write to these settings whenever they need. Does it make sense for a thread to call getBlahSetting() and get one result, and in the same function moments later call it again and get a _different result_? I suggest you design in a hard synchronization point.

Comment: Setting should only ever change on the user's behalf, and an user can rarely do more than one thing concurrently. Insofar, there shouldn't ever be more than one writer. I would therefore access ( = read) the config without any synchronization at all (since it happens frequently). Make a deep copy from the modifying thread for the rare case that config is changed (again, this needs not be synchronized). Then do a single `seq_cst` store to the pointer to the config object which everyone uses (that's expensive, but you can afford that, since it happens rarely), and be done. It may take ...

Comment: ... a moment before other threads pick up the change, but that usually isn't a problem. They will, eventually. If this *is a problem*, you have no choice but to use locks (presumably a reader-writer lock), and then performance will stink. Alternatively, threads could keep local copies (or share a ref-counted copy) of the config state, and _explicitly_ be notified to update config via the task queue, at a well-defined time. That eliminates the possible races.

Comment: Thing is, all those atomics are not likely to help you a lot, if for example you modify some string, atomically, and a TCP endpoint, atomically, but then another thread (or two of them) pick up the new string value with the wrong TCP endpoint and such. It matters little whether each was updated atomically if the ensemble of the config is nonsensical. Unless of course, this doesn't matter to you. The only reasonably safe method is to either use a reader-writer lock, or to explicitly acquire new config (as in, a "snapshot" via a new pointer to a complete, new config set) at defined times.

Comment: @Damon This (these, actually) should be an answer, I believe.

Comment: @Dave: This does make sense in my case. Most of the settings will be read inside a processing loop. With every iteration of this loop I just need the most recent value.

Comment: @Damon: Thanks for your explanations. My settings are quite unrelated to each other. So I don't have the problem of the whole set of settings being in a nonsensical state in my case. If, for some reason, a string and an endpoint need to be in a consistent state, I would take them together and consider them as one complex setting as in Question 4. So synchronizing the settings individually does make sense in my case.

Comment: @Damon: However I will still have to think about your suggestion of replacing the whole config at once. However I'm not sure this will fit nicely into my program design. (The setting class in my question is just a simplified version to illustrate my question).

Answer (score 2):

Q1, Correct if you don't try to read any shared non-atomic variables after reading the atomic. Memory barriers only synchronize access to non-atomic variables that may happen  between atomic operations

Q2 I don't know (but see below)

Q3 Should work (if compiles). However,

```
 atomic<string>
```

possibly isn't lock free

Q4 Should work but, again, the implementation isn't possibly lockfree (Implementing lockfree shared_ptr is challenging and patent-mined field).

So probably readers-writers lock (as  Damon suggests in the comments) may be simpler and even more effective if your config includes data with size more than 1 machine word (for which CPU native atomics usually works)

[EDIT]However,

```
atomic<shared_ptr<TheWholeStructContainigAll> >
```

may have some sense even being non-lock free: this approach minimize collision probability for readers that need more than one coherent value, though the writer should make a new copy of the whole "parameter sheet" every time it changes something.

Comment: `boost::atomic<std::string>` does compile but it doesn't work. I get a debug assertion when I try to load it. It says: "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" in "crt\src\dbgdel.cpp" (VC++ 2012). Sometimes I just get an access violation. If I wrap my `std::string` with a `std::atomic` I can load the value but I get an access violation when I store it...

Answer (score 2):

For question **1**, the answer is "depends, but probably not". If you really only care that a single value isn't garbled, then yes, this is fine, and you don't care about memory order either.
Usually, though, this is a false premise.

For questions **2**, **3**, and **4** yes, this will work, but it will likely use locking for complex objects such as `string` (internally, for every access, without you knowing). Only rather small objects which are roughly the size of one or two pointers can normally be accessed/changed atomically in a lockfree manner. This depends on your platform, too.

It's a big difference whether one successfully updates one or two values atomically. Say you have the values `left` and `right` which delimit the left and right boundaries of where a task will do some processing in an array. Assume they are 50 and 100, respectively, and you change them to 101 and 150, each atomically. So the other thread picks up the change from 50 to 101 and starts doing its calculation, sees that 101 > 100, finishes, and writes the result to a file. After that, you change the output file's name, again, atomically.
Everything was atomic (and thus, more expensive than normal), but none of it was useful. The result is still wrong, and was written to the wrong file, too.
This may not be a problem in your particular case, but usually it is (and, your requirements may change in the future). Usually you *really* want the *complete set* of changes being atomic.

That said, if you have either many or complex (or, both many and complex) updates like this to do, you might want to use one big (reader-writer) lock for the whole config in the first place anyway, since that is more efficient than acquiring and releasing 20 or 30 locks or doing 50 or 100 atomic operations. Do however note that in any case, locking will severely impact performance.

As pointed out in the comments above, I would preferrably make a deep copy of the configuration from the one thread that modifies the configuration, and schedule updates of the reference (shared pointer) used by consumers as a normal tasks. That copy-modify-publish approach a bit similar to how MVCC databases work, too (these, too, have the problem that locking kills their performance).

Modifying a copy asserts that only readers are accessing any shared state, so no synchronization is necessary either for readers or for the single writer. Reading and writing is fast.
Swapping the configuration set happens only at well-defined points in times when the set is guaranteed to be in a complete, consistent state and threads are guaranteed not to do something else, so no ugly surprises of any kind can happen.

A typical task-driven application would look somewhat like this (in C++-like pseudocode):

```
// consumer/worker thread(s)
for(;;)
{
    task = queue.pop();

    switch(task.code)
    {
        case EXIT:
            return;

        case SET_CONFIG:
            my_conf = task.data;
            break;

        default:
            task.func(task.data, &my_conf); // can read without sync
    }
}


// thread that interacts with user (also producer)
for(;;)
{
    input = get_input();

    if(input.action == QUIT)
    {
        queue.push(task(EXIT, 0, 0));
        for(auto threads : thread)
            thread.join();
        return 0;
    }
    else if(input.action == CHANGE_SETTINGS)
    {
        new_config = new config(config); // copy, readonly operation, no sync
        // assume we have operator[] overloaded
        new_config[...] = ...;           // I own this exclusively, no sync

        task t(SET_CONFIG, 0, shared_ptr<...>(input.data));
        queue.push(t);
    }
    else if(input.action() == ADD_TASK)
    {
        task t(RUN, input.func, input.data);
        queue.push(t);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like `boost::atomic<std::string>` doesn't work. I get a debug assertion when I try to load it. It says: "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" in "crt\src\dbgdel.cpp" (VC++ 2012). Sometimes I just get an access violation. If I wrap my `std::string` with a `std::atomic` I can load the value but I get an access violation when I store it...

Answer (score 2):

For anything more substantial than a pointer, use a mutex. The tbb (opensource) library supports the concept of reader-writer mutices, which allow multiple simultaneous readers, see the [documentation](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/467774).